# Font Awesome 5 "solid" square rendering instead of "regular"

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm trying to use the Font Awesome 5 square icon here:
https://fontawesome.com/icons/square?style=regular

I'd like to use the "regular" version, that is simply the square outline, but no matter what I do, it always renders as the "solid" version. From what I have read, the regular is suppose to be the default, and to make it solid use a font-weight of 900. But, the default here seems to be solid, and I've tried several different font weights and it doesn't change anything.

Below is what I'm talking about. The commented out font-weights are all the different ones I tried, but they don't make a difference...

```css
label:before
{
    content: "\f0c8";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #ccc;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    /*font-weight: 100;*/
    /*font-weight: 400;*/
    /*font-weight: 900;*/
    /*font-weight: normal;*/
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
  <label>Label Text</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the one above not work? When I was created it, it properly picked up the icons for me.

Comment: V5 is not V4, change the font-family